Denormalizing an IEEE 754 32-bit number
From what I understand, it is of the form $-1^s * 1.mantissa * 2^e$, where s is the sign, and e is the true exponent.
In this question, where sign = 0,
Exponent = 0011 0100 and
mantissa = 0100 0110 0000 0000 0100 000, how exactly do I denormalize and find the actual decimal number?
I'm told it is something like $1.27344...*2^{-75}$, but I'm not convinced with how the mantissa has been handled. I feel it is even arithmetically wrong, since the matissa is coming out to be 2293760.

How are you getting 2293760?

That is not what denormalizing means. See e.g. this Wikipedia article (which uses the now-preferred term subnormal instead).

You seem to have missed a 1 bit. The number I get is 2293792, interpreting the bits as a 23-bit integer. Personally I find it more intuitive to interpret them directly as a fraction whose first few bits are 0.0100011.

@BenGrossmann my bad, I missed a bit. Adding 2^5 to my calculation gives the right value

Your $1.[\cdots]$ portion of the number can be expressed as
$$
\frac{[1\,0100\,0110\,0000\,0000\,0100\,000]_2}{[1\,0000\,0000\,0000\,0000\,0000\,000]_2} = \frac{10682400}{2^{23}} = 1.2734413146972656,
$$
which matches up with what you've been told.
You have correctly computed the exponent
$$
e = [0011\,0100]_2 - [0011\,1111]_2 = -75.
$$
